# Create solid shadow effect on text using Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

Is there a way in Photoshop to create the text effect seen on the words "chart" "when" and "present" in this image that does not involve drawing the shapes one at a time?

[image: Alex Fowkes]

Comment: What's wrong with simply duplicating the text, changing the color to black, and offsetting it behind the text?

Comment: That causes issues on corners. For example if you do it on a capital "T" the lower right hand corner will have a stair-step.

Comment: Realize in your sample those are *fonts designed with the shadow*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Motion Blur` to fake an extrusion, then use levels to flood the blurred area with a fill.

Blur a copy of your type, and merge it on a background:

[image]

Use levels to flood the fill of the blurred type:

[image]

Invert your original type and position to one side:

[image]

Finish by applying a stroke effect to the inside

[image]

Comment: This is great. I did seem to struggle with the levels part though. Doing it that way didn't affect it, and doing it as an adjustment layer worked but affected the rest of the image.

In the end I did that step with the paint bucket fill and it worked okay.